# Setting Date Picker With JavaScript And PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to set a date picker with JS like any other `<input>` value.

This HTML line works, but I need to set the value with Java.

```
<input Id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="date" required value="<?php echo $BirthDate ?>" >
```

However when I try to use the `.value` attribute  the date picker stays blank.

```
<input Id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="date" required >
```

Currently I am using this script to set the picker, This function runs as soon as the page loads the body.

```
function StartUp() {                        

document.getElementById("BirthDate").value = "<?php echo $BirthDate ?>";

}                   
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? 
And what else could I try to use?

Comment: are you sure the function is running, and the dom is ready at that point?

Comment: What exactly the content of $birthDate in PHP?

Comment: @Danny No, I'm not sure that its is loading. but I have a second page that uses the same-ish code. But it doesn't use PHP for the value, it uses a JS value.

Comment: @Amina  a date in this format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Try to change the date format.
http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @Amina Okay...Ill look at it. But the Echo is working in the first example. and the value comes from a date picker and is left in the same format it came in.
why would  it need to be changed?

Comment: Where/how do you call `StartUp()`?

Comment: @Danny  In the div tag that starts the body `<body onload="StartUp()">` then there are a couple other tags that com after that.

Comment: @Danny I have a different pages that use the same code except the PHP Echo.

Comment: @Danny The problem is with the echo, I hard coded a date in the java and it worked and i just printed the PHP as plain text on the page fine. Why would the PHP not be printing a value?

Comment: Can't be sure of that, not familiar enough with php. The code looks right the only thing I can think of is that `$BirthDate` hasn't been assigned to a value at that point yet.

Comment: @Danny No, the PHP runs long before the Java as the Server does all of it. the html page that the client gets all ready have the values printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working no, something was being difficult with the syntax of the php.

changing:

```
document.getElementById("BirthDate").value = "<?php echo $BirthDate ?>";
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("BirthDate").value = "<?php echo($BirthDate); ?>";
```

Adding `() parentheses` around my variable and a `; semicolon` after the command fixed my issue.